# How can I deploy an application to Hololens without VS?

Tags: package, hololens

I've developed an application for Hololens, so the only way I know to install the application in hololens is by visual studio, so I want an application package to be able to install without needing Visual Studio. I tried to follow this tutorial here

"https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool"

but I can not find these two .appx and .appxsym files.

If anyone knew, I appreciate that.

Comment: I am sorry my English

Comment: Do you want to *build* without VS or simply *deploy* without VS?

Comment: install without VS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you know some steps, but I will go the full way (it's only deploying without visual Studio):

- In Unity:

  - File> Build Settings
  - Choose Universal Windows Plattform (older Versions Windows Store). Make sure your settings are right (for hololens, sdk enabled...)
  - hit "Build"
  - Now you have to select a Folder to build. In my Projects I create just an "App" Folder
- Once it is build navigate to this Folder (if it's not opening automatically).

  - Open the Solution (in the App Folder, not the Unity one)
  - In the Explorer right Click on the "Project Properties" which are named like your Project and Select "Store>create App Package (or maybe build, i got it on German)"
  - If you want only the appx File select "no" at the Windows Store question
  - Select an Output Folder and Version Number (count's up itself, newer numbers will overwrite older versions on Hololens automatically) and for Hololens only select x86 (the others are not needed. Just consume time). Now hit the "create"(again i hope i translate it right) Button.
- Apply on Hololens:

  - Connect the hololens via USB (you can do it with wifi too, but not in our Network, so i never tried)
  - Open a browser and type "127.0.0.1:10080" so you get access to your hololens
  - Navigate to "System>Apps" and under Install App select the appx file (in my case under: (myUnityProject/**App**/AppPackages/myUnityProject/myUnityProject_1.0.0.0_Win32_Master_Test)
  - First time deploying select the dependencies (Dependencies/x86)
  - Hit "go" to Deploy (wait until everything is uploaded)

Some Notes:

To build the Apps i needed mvs 2015 installed (just installed), but this was before the Fall creators Update. Now newer Versions (should) work fine. Also I needed to install the windows "buildtools 2015" 
https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Hope it works and have fun!

Comment: It worked very well, thank you very much. There is a detail when uploading, the user must remain on the browser screen until the upload is finished.

Comment: Will add it. Sry i didn't saw this.

Comment: mark it as answer, if it was right. so the post gets closed :-)

Comment: An error occurs when leaving the upload screen for Hololens, I do not know why. You have to stay on the screen until the upload is finished. At least in Mozilla Firefox. Thank you very munch.

Comment: OK. I will do this

Comment: The instructions are unclear. "Open the Solution". Open which file, using what? "In the Explorer right Click on the 'Project Properties'". I can't see that in the explorer.

Comment: In my example in the "App" Folder you created is Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File (should be named like your app). Double click it. MVS should open. Now right click on the Project Properties(first entry in the Project Folder) and "Store>create App Package" and so on...